# Netbeans 7.1.2 Mac 0S X download

Tags: macos, netbeans, operating-system, java

I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8 and am trying to run Netbeans 7.1.2. When I run Netbeans I get the following message:

```
Cannot run on older versions of Java than Java 6 Standard Edition. Please install JAva 6 
Standard Edition or newer or use --jdkhome switch to point to its installation director.
```

Anyway, I am pretty sure I have JDK 1.6 as I have navigated to /Libary/Java and have found a 
file that says JDK 1.6.

I tried to download the lastest JDK from Oracle (JDK 1.7) and when I try to open the installer, my mac says:

```
This Installer is supported only on OS X Lion (10.7.0)
```

What can I do? I am running out of ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a package of [both](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to /Applications/Utilities/JavaPreferences (or something similar) and the current jdk can be set there.

Answer (score 1):

Set the JDK home path in `netbeans.conf` file, more details [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf).

See the option *`netbeans_jdkhome`* option in `Editing the Configuration File` section

Hope it helps